# php regex: Use quotes for match, but don't capture them

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm unsure if I should be using preg_match, preg_match_all, or preg_split with delim capture. I'm also unsure of the correct regex.

Given the following:

```
$string = " ok 'that\\'s cool' \"yeah that's \\\"cool\\\"\"";
```

I want to get an array with the following elems:

```
[0] = "ok"
[1] = "that\'s"
[2] = "yeah that's \"cool\""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this with a regular expression because you're trying to parse a **non-context-free grammar**. Write a parser.

Outline:

- read character by character, if you see a `\` remember it.
- if you see a `"` or `'` check if the previous character was `\`. You now have your delimiting condition.
- record all the tokens in this manner

Your desired result set seems to trim spaces, you also lost a couple of the `\`s, perhaps this is a mistake but it can be important.

I would expect:

```
[0] = " ok " // <-- spaces here
[1] = "that\\'s cool"
[2] = " \"yeah that's \\\"cool\\\"\"" // leading space here, and \" remains
```

Comment: You're welcome to try your hand at a regexp that does this - without any errors.

Comment: Yes, my desired result would trim spaces. I'd just want \S if not in quotes, and any content inside quotes would include spaces.

Comment: Also, wouldn't your second bullet point produce errors? For example, if you have \\', the character before the ' is a \, but it is not intended to escape it.

Comment: Oh in that cause you could always count the number of \, if it's even you act like there is no \.

Comment: I've finished making a parser. Work's like a charm; thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you might be surprised to find that you *can* do this in regex:

```
preg_match_all("((?|\"((?:\\\\.|[^\"])+)\"|'((?:\\\\.|[^'])+)'|(\w+)))",$string,$m);
```

The desired result array will be in `$m[1]`.

Comment: `$string = "\\'a'"` doesn't seem to give the right result, expected: `"\\'a"`, got: `"a"`

Comment: `$string = " ok 'that\\\\\\\\'s cool' \"yeah that's \\\"cool\\\"\"";` also doesn't seem to give the right result.

Comment: what is this "(?|"? is it supposed to be "(?:"?

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) is there for a reason ;)

Comment: Ah, sorry, the reference I was using was incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a regex:

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
(?J) 

# Definitions #
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<ens> (?> \\{2} )+ ) # even number of backslashes

  (?<sqc> (?> [^\s'\\]++  | \s++ (?!'|$)    | \g<ens> | \\ '?+    )+ ) # single quotes content
  (?<dqc> (?> [^\s"\\]++  | \s++ (?!"|$)    | \g<ens> | \\ "?+    )+ ) # double quotes content
  (?<con> (?> [^\s"'\\]++ | \s++ (?!["']|$) | \g<ens> | \\ ["']?+ )+ ) # content
)
# Pattern #
    \s*+ (?<res> \g<con>)
| ' \s*+ (?<res> \g<sqc>) \s*+ '?+
| " \s*+ (?<res> \g<dqc>) \s*+ "?+ 
~x
LOD;
$subject = " ok 'that\\'s cool' \"yeah that's \\\"cool\\\"\"";

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($matches as $match) {
    var_dump($match['res']);
}
```

I made the choice to trim spaces in all results, then `" abcd "` will give `abcd`. This pattern allows all backslashes you want, anywhere you want. If a quoted string is not closed at the end of the string, the end of the string is considered as the closing quote *(this is why i have made the closing quotes optional)*. So, `abcd " ef'gh` will give you `abcd` and `ef'gh`